# cover image not laying out responsively for mobile devices,

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

The cover image is fit nicely for tablets and larger devices, but it is not fit into the small devices like mobile phones.

Here is the html using bootstrap,

```css
 .background {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #292929;
      background-size: cover !important;
      background-position: 50% 50% !important;
    }
```

```html
  <section class="fullscreen">
         <div class="background">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
         </div>
       </section>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: add a code snippet

Comment: Background-size and position does not work with html `<img>` it's just for background-image (when you call the image with css)

Answer (score 0):

I've added this css to your image:

```
.background img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.fullscreen{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #292929;
}

.background img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
   <section class="fullscreen">
     <div class="background">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293__340.jpg" />
     </div>
   </section>
```